# Trying to uninstall skype

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to uninstall Skype and Skype for Business.  The major problem that I am having is that neither app is showing up on the uninstall screen of control panel.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure they actually installed?

Comment: " If you are using Office 365 Skype for Business, you can't delete it from your computer without also uninstalling the rest of the Office suite. This because it's integrated with the other Office apps. The following instructions are for customers who have standalone versions of Skype for Business.".....https://support.office.com/en-us/article/uninstall-skype-for-business-28c4a036-7f22-406c-b7f4-87894cbaf902

Answer (score 2):

Skype for business is installed with Office so when you go to add or remove programs or use control panel and access Programs and Features you'll find the install for office and when you select uninstall it should give you the option to change the features of office. If you select modify you should be able to see what features of office are installed, uncheck Skype for Business and it will be removed from your system and no longer available.